# Get hash value Rails / Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chart.js

Hello I'm coding a form generator in RoR and I want to generate several charts for any of my questions. For my question x I have this results

```
 {"answer1"=>2, "answer2"=>2, "answer3"=>1, ...}
```

I want to know how i can access the second data (the numbers) and in general how to set the 'label' and 'data' fields on the Chart.js script :

```
 answer= [<% for rep in @polls4 %>
         "<%= rep.nom %>",
         <% end %>];
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data:  {
    labels:answer,
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: ?,
        backgroundColor: [
```

My @polls4 is defined in my controller by

```
 @polls4 = @polls.where(question_id: 4).group("nom")
```

Thank you

Comment: You want to labels = [ 'answer1', 'answer2', ...] and data = [ 2, 2, ... ]. Did I get right?

Comment: @hamdi Yes that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead adding a loop in your JS, initialize the polls variable as an array of ids, this way you avoid having to collect them, and adding Ruby logic in the JS code:

```
@polls4 = @polls.where('question_id = ?', 4).pluck(:nom)
```

As you're grouping you get that hash of key/value data, using pluck you get just the id of each Poll:

So the chart:

```
var answer = "<%= @polls4 %>";
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { 
  ...
});
```

I'd recommend you to rename the @polls4 variable to something more descriptive and avoiding using numbers in variable names.

Comment: Thank you @sebastianPalma !